# showDirectoryPicker() to display directory path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using window.showDirectoryPicker() to retrieve and save directory handle to IndexedDB.

My question - is there a way to display the whole path of the selected directory? (not just the directory name)

Thanks!

Reference: https://web.dev/file-system-access/

Answer (score 1):

No [you can't](https://github.com/WICG/file-system-access/issues/282). That's a frequently asked feature but the privacy risks are too high for the specs authors to allow this.

Maybe the feature proposed in [#156](https://github.com/WICG/file-system-access/issues/156) could help for your use case, as it aims at exposing a web-API able to open the folder where your handle lives using the OS file manager. However even this is not going to be ready soon...